# Ln as a valid word?

Tags: vocabulary

I have started playing the German language version of Words With Friends. I play with one friend who used to be my German teacher in high school. But I also play with a computer opponent, and was dumbfounded by a "word" it played during one of our sessions: Ln.

I couldn't imagine it being a valid word as it looked more like an abbreviation. I also consulted the various online dictionaries and translation tools but without success.

Should I consider this a bug in the game, or is there such a word?

Comment: Sind Abkürzungen im Spiel denn erlaubt? Wörter ohne Vokal gibt es im Deutschen generell nicht. Der Logarithmus Naturalis wird so abgekürzt, womöglich weiteres. Neben Wörterbüchern ist Wikipedia eine weitere, gute Quelle: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LN

Comment: Ln (mit großem L) für den natürlichen Logarithmus ist mindestens unüblich. Als mathematisches Schlüsselwort wird er eigentlich immer kleingeschrieben.

Comment: In der Mathematik kann Ln für Logarithmus naturalis stehen: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmus

Comment: Are you sure that it was "Ln" not "In" with a capitalized "i"? Even in Mathematics you write the natural Logarithm "ln" with lower case "L" not "Ln"!

Comment: [Mhhhhh](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hm), @userunknown, ob es da nicht doch Wörter ohne Vokal gibt...

Comment: @Em1 Hmm, gute Frage. Aber dieser sarkastische Unterton? Tz, tz, tz....

Comment: @MediSaif: Ich kenne words-with-friends nicht, vielleicht ist das wie Scrabble und unterscheidet nicht in der Schreibung.

Comment: Hm ist vielleicht ein Laut, aber kein zertifiziertes Qualitätswort. :)

Comment: According to duden.de it is an abbreviation of "Leinenband"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be that `ln.` is used as an abbreviation in some professional context but I consider this not to be a valid German word.

What may have happened here is that the preposition `in` was (erroneously) capitalized and rendered with a sans serif font such as e.g. Arial. Then the capitalized `i` (top) and the `l` (bottom) are identical:

[image]
<sup>left **Arial** - right **Times New Roman**</sup>

Note that we capitalize `in` only at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: ... and many feminists in the middle of a word. :)

Comment: Daran hatte ich auch gedacht - aber warum sollte der OP dann ausdrücklich Ln mit großem 'L' geschrieben haben?

Answer (score 2):

Never saw it in use, but according to the Duden "authority", it is a [valid, albeit seldomly used abbreviation for Leineneinband](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ln_), probably used by librarians or antiquarians.

If the game considers abbreviations to be valid solutions, then all is good.

Answer (score 1):

"Ln" is definitely no German word.

Edit (short explanation):
Every German word *must* have one of the following letters: a, e, i, o, u, ä, ö, ü or in very rare cases y.

Comment: Es gibt Antworten die keiner längeren Erklärung bedürfen. Wenn es ein Wort nicht gibt, dann gibt es das nicht. Gäbe es jetzt einen Grund, wieso es das Wort geben sollte, dann wäre eine Erklärung, wieso die Gründe nicht durchschlagen erwünscht - so lädt die Aufforderung nur zu leerem Gelaber ein. "Steht nicht zwischen Liz und Lob im Duden" - das ergibt sich ja schnurstracks aus der Behauptung, dass es das Wort nicht gibt.

Comment: Ok, actually you are right.
Exceptions confirm the rule ;-)
Of course you can use ä,ö,ü in valid German words instead of a,e,i,o,u, i forgot to mention.
German words without one of these letters but with an y for example are very very rare.

Comment: The *Duden* [lists](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pst)  `pst` . Either not all words contain a vowel; or we cannot use the *Duden* to define what a word is.